# How does the life of Muhammad, the Prophet of Islam, compare to the standards of the Bible?

Tags: islam, comparative-religion

Muhammad claimed to be God's Prophet, even God's Last Prophet.  As such his life should measure up as a godly life.  Using only the most approved Muslim sources, the Qur'an, and the most highly regarded Hadith i.e. the Sahih Bukhari, the Sahih Muslim and Sunan Abu Daud, and Guillaume's "Life of Muhammed" how does Muhammad's life compare with the standards of the Bible?  Or how does his life compare with the life of our Lord Jesus?  Is there anything to cause us to doubt his status as a prophet?

I am not really interested in his teachings.  I appreciate that is very important, but other questions can address that.  I just want to have answers about his behaviour.

Comment: As written, this question is definitely close-worthy because answers must make a value judgment regarding what the Bible teaches.  However, recasting it somewhat – and adjusting answers accordingly – as something like "On what basis do Evangelical [or Catholic, or Mormon, etc.] apologists argue that Muhammad committed sin?" would result in much more focused answers and less debate.

Comment: @Nathaniel - Thanks.  But if I posted a question such as "On what basis do evangelicals... etc", how would it not get deleted if I posted more or less the same answer?

Comment: @Nathaniel - Also, I am being accused of hate-speech (!), using biased sources, making offensive statements.  What I am really doing is putting statements together which are all usually swept under the carpet, statements from the Qur'an itself and statements which are written _by Muslims_, in the most highly regarded sources of hadith _**that exist in the Muslim world**_.  This is surely of value, when Islam claims to supercede Christianity, and it is claimed the Qur'an trumps the Bible.

Comment: The beauty of answering "here's what evangelical apologist A says and here's how evangelical organization B argues" is that you are describing the viewpoint of a Christian group/tradition.  It may happen to correspond with your own view, but that's not the focus, and any comments challenging the views you present can be swiftly rebutted by saying "are you saying that I have failed to accurately capture the views of evangelical apologist A?"

Comment: Another way to look at this – your answer seems to be an attempt to demonstrate that *Islam* believes certain things, and this naturally raises the hackles of people who disagree with you.  But if we remember that this site is meant to be used as a way to share what *Christian traditions* believe, then answers can share how Christian traditions deal with certain aspects of other religions.

Comment: @Nathaniel - OK, thanks, I will have a rethink.

Comment: For an example within "christendom," broadly defined, I wrote a question and answer on the issues that Protestants have with Swedenborgianism.  If my question had been "Why is Swedenborgianism wrong," it would have been disastrous.  But I was able to fit my question to the format by asking for, and then providing, the views of Protestant apologists who have studied Swedenborgianism.

Comment: Given our site scoping rules "What does the Bible say about X" or "What about X according to the Bible" are off topic questions across the board no matter what X is. "Christianity" and "The Bible" are simply not sufficient scopes for questions. You need to conceptually rethink what you are asking and who you are asking it of, then pare this down to something that is answerable given our site guidelines.

Comment: @Caleb - OK, thanks. I'm still learning about the site.